# Ubuntu/Windows 10 Dual Boot: Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 using a bootable USB which I've successfully used to do this many times.

I have disabled fast startup and secure boot. But when I boot from the USB drive (listed as UEFI Gendisk disk 5.00) I am immediately met with the following

```
[0.129589] Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
[7.283474] nouveau 0000:17:00.0: disp: chid mthd 0614 data 4c7b4c7b 00003614 00000000
```

Does anyone know what would be going on here? I am trying to install on an Acer Predator equipped with 2 NVIDIA 1080TIs. The nouveau in the message leads me to believe this is related to the graphics cards somehow.

Comment: this may be a good read for your issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/670509/error-parsing-pcc-subspaces-from-pcct-acpi-pcc-probe-failed

Comment: seems many folks got this. For nVidia 1080TI you have to load the drivers after install.

Comment: @Acewin the issue however is that I cannot install. Booting from the disk insta-crashes to a black screen with the errors I showed above.

Comment: I have shared a link for `Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT`

Comment: are you considering your disk drive is faulty ??. Does your windows boot up correctly ??